# Spark standalone master HA jobs in WAITING status

Tags: apache-spark

We are trying to setup HA on spark standalone master using zookeeper. 
We have two zookeeper hosts which we are using for spark ha as well.

Configured following thing in spark-env.sh

```
SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.deploy.recoveryMode=ZOOKEEPER -Dspark.deploy.zookeeper.url=zk_server1:2181,zk_server2:2181"
```

Started both the masters.

started shell and status of the job is RUNNING.
master1 is in ALIVE and master2 is in STANDBY status.
Killed the master1 and master2 has been picked up and all the workers appeared alive in master2.

The shell which is already running has been moved to new master. However, the status is in WAITING status and executors are in LOADING status.

No error in worker log and executor log, except notification that connected to new master.

I could see the worker re-registered, but the executor does not seems to be started. Is there any thing that i am missing.?

My spark version is 1.5.0

Comment: Similar problem here with Spark 1.6.2: the application remains in state `WAITING` but my executors are in state `RUNNING`...

Comment: If i started and configured zookeeper on one of the spark cluster machines/spark master, it did worked. But not stable enough. In the above case, i have used separate zookeeper cluster.